# Parsing big data from datatebles

Tags: php, parsing, datatables

I need to parse data from data tables there http://ki.arbitr.gov.ua/sud5011/700/csz/

The problem is - all the data generating via JS and I can't get the data like PHP looking the page)
http://ki.arbitr.gov.ua/new.php - this ajax query generated the data on the server, but if I send any query to the http://ki.arbitr.gov.ua/new.php - I received only "error code: hgjfv7"

I will be glad to any thinking about or any solutions, thanks to all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to get here so curl request**

```
curl 'http://ki.arbitr.gov.ua/new.php' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=qmvdf773bcv16tlqpu3p0148k7' -H 'Origin: http://ki.arbitr.gov.ua' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: http://ki.arbitr.gov.ua/sud5011/700/csz/' --data 'q_court_id=5011' --compressed
```

I get this curl with Google Chrome Console

> http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/16/0524/h_1464076260_8013082_9301b1622e.png

Comment: Thanks, Maxim, it really helps me!

Comment: Also, I have find great service for curl to php curl converting) https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/